# Use Runningcoder Jquery Typeahead with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

This is the plugin I want to use with Bootstrap 3: [Runningcoder Jquery Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/overview/).
My goal is to use it with a  search field in a bootstrap navbar.
In the [documentation](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) it is clearly stated that this plugin;
- is compatible with Bootstrap 3 (but there are no demos)
- The Typeahead plugin requires a specific HTML structure (see ["html structure and css"](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) section at the beginnning of the documentation)
- The 'selector' option can be used to override classes on elements to inherit from your website's UI elements, for example giving a Bootstrap look

So, what html and js do I need to use to implement this plugin in a bootstrap navbar?
(For example let's try to implement the very basic ["Country v1" demo](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/))

Of course I've already tried many code variations but nothing worked. I'm not posting any code since it wouldn't be useful (the starting point is the code of the demo linked above)

Answer (score 0):

**`Html`**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="Bootstrap">BOOTSTRAP!!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <var id="result-container" class="result-container"></var>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**`javascript:`**

```
$('#srch-term').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    order: "asc",
    href: "https://en.wikipedia.org/?title={{display}}",
    template: "{{display}} <small style='color:#999;'>{{group}}</small>",
    source: {
        country: {
            url: ["/jquerytypeahead/country_v2.json", "data.country"]
        },
        capital: {
            url: [
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/jquerytypeahead/country_v2.json",
                    data: {myKey: "myValue"}
                },
                "data.capital"
            ]
        }
    },
    callback: {
        onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {

            var r = confirm("You will be redirected to:\n" + item.href + "\n\nContinue?");
            if (r == true) {
                window.open(item.href);
            }

            $('#result-container').text('');

        },
        onResult: function (node, query, obj, objCount) {

            var text = "";
            if (query !== "") {
                text = objCount + ' elements matching "' + query + '"';
            }
            $('#result-container').text(text);

        },
        onMouseEnter: function (node, a, obj, e) {

            if (obj.group === "country") {
                $(a).append('<span class="flag-chart flag-' + obj.display.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() + '"></span>')
            }

        },
        onMouseLeave: function (node, a, obj, e) {

            $(a).find('.flag-chart').remove();

        }
    }
});
```

**`PHP`**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    "status"    => true,
    "error"     => null,
    "data"      => array(
        "country"   => array(
                "AfghanisTan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
                "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
                "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
                "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
                "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
                "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
                "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
                "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
                "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon",
                "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea",
                "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
                "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
                "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
                "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
                "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
                "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco",
                "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
                "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
                "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino",
                "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",
                "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain",
                "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan",
                "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
                "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
                "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
            ),
        "capital"   => array(
            "Abu Dhabi", "Abuja", "Accra", "Adamstown", "Addis Ababa", "Algiers", "Alofi", "Amman", "Amsterdam",
            "Andorra la Vella", "Ankara", "Antananarivo", "Apia", "Ashgabat", "Asmara", "Astana", "Asunción", "Athens",
            "Avarua", "Baghdad", "Baku", "Bamako", "Bandar Seri Begawan", "Bangkok", "Bangui", "Banjul", "Basseterre",
            "Beijing", "Beirut", "Belgrade", "Belmopan", "Berlin", "Bern", "Bishkek", "Bissau", "Bogotá", "Brasília",
            "Bratislava", "Brazzaville", "Bridgetown", "Brussels", "Bucharest", "Budapest", "Buenos Aires", "Bujumbura",
            "Cairo", "Canberra", "Caracas", "Castries", "Cayenne", "Charlotte Amalie", "Chisinau", "Cockburn Town",
            "Conakry", "Copenhagen", "Dakar", "Damascus", "Dhaka", "Dili", "Djibouti", "Dodoma", "Doha", "Douglas",
            "Dublin", "Dushanbe", "Edinburgh of the Seven Seas", "El Aaiún", "Episkopi Cantonment", "Flying Fish Cove",
            "Freetown", "Funafuti", "Gaborone", "George Town", "Georgetown", "Georgetown", "Gibraltar", "King Edward Point",
            "Guatemala City", "Gustavia", "Hagåtña", "Hamilton", "Hanga Roa", "Hanoi", "Harare", "Hargeisa", "Havana",
            "Helsinki", "Honiara", "Islamabad", "Jakarta", "Jamestown", "Jerusalem", "Juba", "Kabul", "Kampala",
            "Kathmandu", "Khartoum", "Kiev", "Kigali", "Kingston", "Kingston", "Kingstown", "Kinshasa", "Kuala Lumpur",
            "Kuwait City", "Libreville", "Lilongwe", "Lima", "Lisbon", "Ljubljana", "Lomé", "London", "Luanda", "Lusaka",
            "Luxembourg", "Madrid", "Majuro", "Malabo", "Malé", "Managua", "Manama", "Manila", "Maputo", "Marigot",
            "Maseru", "Mata-Utu", "Mbabane Lobamba", "Melekeok Ngerulmud", "Mexico City", "Minsk", "Mogadishu", "Monaco",
            "Monrovia", "Montevideo", "Moroni", "Moscow", "Muscat", "Nairobi", "Nassau", "Naypyidaw", "N'Djamena",
            "New Delhi", "Niamey", "Nicosia", "Nicosia", "Nouakchott", "Nouméa", "Nukuʻalofa", "Nuuk", "Oranjestad",
            "Oslo", "Ottawa", "Ouagadougou", "Pago Pago", "Palikir", "Panama City", "Papeete", "Paramaribo", "Paris",
            "Philipsburg", "Phnom Penh", "Plymouth Brades Estate", "Podgorica Cetinje", "Port Louis", "Port Moresby",
            "Port Vila", "Port-au-Prince", "Port of Spain", "Porto-Novo Cotonou", "Prague", "Praia", "Cape Town",
            "Pristina", "Pyongyang", "Quito", "Rabat", "Reykjavík", "Riga", "Riyadh", "Road Town", "Rome", "Roseau",
            "Saipan", "San José", "San Juan", "San Marino", "San Salvador", "Sana'a", "Santiago", "Santo Domingo",
            "São Tomé", "Sarajevo", "Seoul", "Singapore", "Skopje", "Sofia", "Sri Jayawardenepura Kotte", "St. George's",
            "St. Helier", "St. John's", "St. Peter Port", "St. Pierre", "Stanley", "Stepanakert", "Stockholm", "Sucre",
            "Sukhumi", "Suva", "Taipei", "Tallinn", "Tarawa Atoll", "Tashkent", "Tbilisi", "Tegucigalpa", "Tehran",
            "Thimphu", "Tirana", "Tiraspol", "Tokyo", "Tórshavn", "Tripoli", "Tskhinvali", "Tunis", "Ulan Bator", "Vaduz",
            "Valletta", "The Valley", "Vatican City", "Victoria", "Vienna", "Vientiane", "Vilnius", "Warsaw",
            "Washington, D.C.", "Wellington", "West Island", "Willemstad", "Windhoek", "Yamoussoukro", "Yaoundé", "Yaren",
            "Yerevan", "Zagreb"
        )
    )
));
```

My suggestion: Sit and code, experiment instead of asking others.

Comment: I already tried various combinations but none of them worked. Either css or js not working properly. Did you try the code that you posted or is this just your own hypothesis?

Comment: Yes. It's not working. No console error but when I type something nothing happens. Your html code has some unused divs and classes and is missing the default (and necessary) ones. I'll ask once again... did you try the solution you posted or is this just your hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

Fixes #65 Added Bootstrap example:

https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/commit/d5e407f54f8f6e073d47c2d24e7cc39d6d360989